# Using Rails Sunspot How can I find primary keys that correspond to facets returned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am wondering whether there is any easy way to get the primary keys of the objects that contribute to a facet result.

In other words, if `search.facet(....).rows.first` returns a `FacetRow`, can I get from this object the subset of the `search.hits` that contribute to this `FacetRow`? If there is a completely different way to go on this, please, let me know.

Note: To get the big picture of my problem (which I think you have probably already got), I want to drill down to the objects that a facet counts for.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `FacetRow` does not contain the actual search results, it contains the count of objects in the current result set that contain the `FacetRow` in question.

In order to get the actual results, i.e., in order to "drill down", you need to execute another search by appending the facet in question to the query that contains the `FacetRow`.

Below is example code describing what I mean. Note, my example is using a facet called "cuisines" from my own project. That string would be whatever your particular facet is. In my own implementation, this snippet is in a partial rendered in a facet iterator so it's repeated for each facet. `@searchResponse` is the return of `Model.search`:

```
  <% for row in @searchResponse.facet('cuisines').rows %>
    <%= link_to(row.instance.name, request.request_uri, facet + '[]=' + row.value.to_s ) %> (<%= row.count %>)</li>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Your answer sounds interesting. Do you have any sample code on that so that I can get a better understanding of what you are mentioning here?